# body on load not works on jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').on('load', function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
    
});
```

But it not works.

Any help?

Comment: incorrect spelling: bory --> body

Comment: sory, I correct but the error continue

Comment: If you're using jQuery 3.x, you need to use `$('body').on('load', function ...)`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I fix the code, the error solved but the code not works

Comment: Have you tried not waiting for the body to load but instead just wrapping it the `document.ready` code by itself?

Comment: I reproduced this, I can't get `$('body').on('load', ...)` to work. But `$(document).ready()` is essentially the same thing, so why do you need both?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to use `$(window).load()` instead of `$('body').on('load'())`.
Then, you need to separate the onload() function and the ready() function:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("fires when webpage is loaded");
  });

  $(window).on('load', function(){
      alert("fires once when window/body has been loaded");
  });
```

Have a look at [this](http://net-informations.com/jq/iq/onload.htm) to understand the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Whay your code does not work?

When `DOMContentLoaded` event fires... That is the event that triggers the `$(document).ready()` callback. Obviouly, the `body` has already loaded too.

So if you ***wait*** for the whole DOM to be loaded to define an event handler about `body` loaded... It will never be executed because that event has fired before the event handler has been defined.

---

And after a close look: There is squarely no "load" event fired for the `body`... Whatever its content.

So as in pythan's answer, that should be `$(window).on("load", function(){...})`

See below:

```js
console.log("before")
$("body").on("load", function () {  // That NEVER fires.
  console.log("Body loaded");
});
console.log("after")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" />
</body>
```

But anyway, you don't need both for sure.